# Dynamically convert Base Class to Derived Class

Tags: c#, casting, derived-class

### For People that don't like to read a lot of Pseudo-Code:

I want to dynamically convert a base class to a derived class based on a variable and then use this newly converted derived class without having to do heavy casting. Is this even possible and if so how can i accomplish it?

### What I'm trying to do in Pseudo-Code:

I have a basic architecture that goes like this:

```
// Base Class:

class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(string data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public string Data { get; set; }
}

// Interface for derived Classes:

interface IStuff
{
    void DoStuff();
}

// Derived Classes: 
// (Don't have own Properties besides the ones they get from BaseClass and 
// no other Methods than they have to implement from IStuff)

class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass, IStuff
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"1: {Data}");
    }
}

class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass, IStuff
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"2: {Data}");
    }
}
```

Now the tricky part: I want to be able to do something like this:

```
UnknownType GetDerivedClass(BaseClass baseClass, int value)
{
    switch(value)
    {
        case 1:
        return baseClass as DerivedClass1;
        case 2:
        return baseClass as DerivedClass2;
        default:
        return null;
    }
}

var value = 1;
var baseClass = new BaseClass("data here");

var derivedClass = GetDerivedClass(baseClass, value);

derivedClass.DoStuff(); // prints "1: data here"
```

In this scenario if i would change the 'value' variable to 2 it would print "2: data here". Is this possible somehow without casting yourself to death or do you have another architectural choice that would make what i'm trying to do a lot easier?

Comment: Is the int variable/parameter necessary?  You could make the method generic, restricted on “where T : BaseClass”, then just “return baseClass as T”

Comment: @maccettura Sadly it can't be generic, i get an Id from an API EndPoint i have no control over and based on that Id i have to use one of the derived classes .

Comment: Looks a lot like trying to solve a surrogate problem. What is the real problem? Apart from that, no, an instance of type A cannot suddenly become an instance of type B, no matter what relationship A and B have.

Comment: @flq I get Urls (~10 different domains; Urls pointing to threads like this one f.e.) from an API Endpoint. Now i want to parse those Urls given to me. Since the threads have the same structures on one domain i need 10 different handlers to parse those threads based on the domain. My BaseClass in this case holds the HttpClient, Url, etc and in the derived class i do the specific parsing of the url. So based on domain name i need to use one of the 10 derived classes in order to parse the content of the url correctly.

Comment: Now there we are :) embrace single responsibility and favor composition: put the httpclient, url etc. in one class, add the right handler to that class‘ instance in the form of its own specific type in the switch statement

Comment: @flq Great this sounds good to me. Could you maybe give me a small snippet of how i would add that class to the instance of my Base Class? And how would i use the HttpClient from the Base Class in this Second Class? Could you maybe post an Answer with my Pseudo Code modified? Danke schon mal für die Hilfe!

Answer (score 0):

It is like you want to instantiate a derived class based on your url or whatever information you know at compile time (because you are using a switch case block and returning class based on known values).

You can use a dictionary in your base class. For example :

```
Dictionary<int,Func<BaseClass>> DerivedClasses ={
    [1] = ()=> new DerivedClass1(),
    [2]= () => new DerivedClass2()
    };
```

Of course, you encapsulate the behavior you want in each derived class.

Now  GetDerivedType(int value) should be in BaseClass and will just return

```
if (DerivedClasses.TryGetValue(value, out var derivedClass))
    return derivedClass;

return null;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  using System;
  namespace ConsoleApp2
  {
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IStuff IStuff = new DerivedClass1("data1 here");
        IStuff.DoStuff(); // prints "1: data here"

        IStuff = new DerivedClass2("data2 here");
        IStuff.DoStuff(); // prints "1: data here"

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class BaseClass
    {
        public BaseClass(string data)
        {
            Data = data;
        }

        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

    // Interface for derived Classes:

    public interface IStuff
    {
        void DoStuff();
    }

    // Derived Classes: 
    // (Don't have own Properties besides the ones they get from BaseClass and 
    // no other Methods than they have to implement from IStuff)

    public class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass, IStuff
    {
        public DerivedClass1(string data) : base(data)
        {

        }
        public void DoStuff()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"1: {Data}");
        }
    }

    public class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass, IStuff
    {
        public DerivedClass2(string data) : base(data)
        {

        }
        public void DoStuff()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"2: {Data}");
        }
    }


    //UnknownType GetDerivedClass(BaseClass baseClass, int value)
    //{
    //    switch (value)
    //    {
    //        case 1:
    //            return baseClass as DerivedClass1;
    //        case 2:
    //            return baseClass as DerivedClass2;
    //        default:
    //            return null;
    //    }
    //}

    //var value = 1;

}
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not very helpful. Consider explaining why your answer solves the OPs problem. Consider fixing your formatting as well, is it really necessary to have a bunch of commented out code?